# Find all occurrences of text in different casing

Tags: full-text-search, replace, case-sensitive

We have an acronym which has specific casing. Business now wants us to find all occurrences where the casing is wrong and fix it.

Example of correct casing: `HtMl`
The search operation would then need to return all occurrences of HTML, html, Html, HtML etc. So I could then examine each case manually to see if it's really our acronym.

I was thinking `Regular Expressions` but I'm unsure how to write one that would exclude the correct case. Something like: `\b((H|h)(T|t)(M|m)(L|l))&(~HTML)\b`. Only `&` as `AND` doesn't exist (or does it?).

Comment: Oracle and files (aspx but this is a one time operation so it doesn't have to be code, if some IDE can do it). HTML was a (bad) example.  Say I'd want it to display `HtMl` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using bash script:

```
echo "Hello, I'm not HtmL, HTML or html, but not HtMl." | grep -o "[H|h][T|t][M|m][L|l]" | grep -v "HtMl"
```

The "exception" is in the "grep -v" part.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the text to lowercase, then find occurrences of the word (lowercased, too) in the lowercased text. Now, whereever you found it in the lowercased version, replace it in the original text.

But now that I think this over, using regular expression is *much* simpler. Not much to add here, but if you have many such replacements to do, here's a little Python script that should generate (and apply) those regular expressions for you.

```
import re
def replaceAllVariants(acronym, text):
    regex = "".join("[%s%s]" % (c.lower(), c.upper()) for c in acronym)
    return re.sub(regex, acronym, text)
# usage
text = replaceAllVariants("HTML", "Bla bla html HTML HtMl hTMl foo bar.")
```

Comment: Hmm, reading your answer, perhaps I've over thought this: If I just replace **all** occurrences and then check in everything, the source control system would cancel all check-outs if the casing was already correct.

Comment: Okay, that was accepted too quickly: Apparently my acronym occurs in other places as well so I want to check each occurrence with different casing manually.